# Change the database from H2 to MySQL for the Spring Boot + Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I developed **Spring Boot OAuth2** example which works fine with the `H2 DB`. Now the same I want to implement for the MySQL DB. What changes do I need to make in order to work with the MySQL DB ?

I am very new to the Spring Security and boot, any help ?

**H2Configuration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class H2Configuration {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean h2servletRegistration() {
        WebServlet webServlet = new WebServlet();
        ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(webServlet);
        bean.addUrlMappings("/h2console/*");
        return bean;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {

        web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/h2console/**")
        .antMatchers("/api/register")
        .antMatchers("/api/activate")
        .antMatchers("/api/lostpassword")
        .antMatchers("/api/resetpassword")
        .antMatchers("/api/hello");

    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
        @Override
        protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
            return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        }

    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
#data source properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:spring_boot_oauth2
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.dataSourceClassName=org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.data=classpath:/sql/data.sql
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# JPA properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.database=H2
spring.jpa.openInView=false
spring.jpa.show_sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none

#web server
server.port=9191
server.contextPath=/api

#Application specific
authentication.oauth.clientid=rajithapp
authentication.oauth.secret=secret
authentication.oauth.tokenValidityInSeconds=1800
```

Comment: Change the approriate db settings. Url, classname, platform...

Comment: `/h2-console` is provided out of the box when using `spring-boot-devtools` or by setting `spring.h2.console.enabled=true`