# Spring Boot: Is it possible to have an h2console connect directly to a MySQL DB?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am intending to have a console on my web app so I can run queries directly from my browser. I can only find guides on how to connect the h2console to an in-memory DB instance. Is this possible? Security isn't an issue, this is strictly for testing purposes, only my ip address will be allowed to connect to the site (for now).

Comment: If down-voting, please provide feedback as to why. I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45924233/change-the-database-from-h2-to-mysql-for-the-spring-boot-spring-security but I am not going to attempt to try this if it will not work. It may be a dumb question but I am brand new to spring boot (and web dev in general).

Comment: I suggest you use PhpMyAdmin to access MySQL. Alternatively you will have to drop relevant JDBC drivers in your classpath and configure to work with H2Console. You might find this answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217656/h2-console-access-for-databases-other-than-h2

Comment: @JSS Is it possible to route a php admin page to apache tomcat? I know I can easily use phpmyadmin but I need to be able to write queries directly on the website.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. PHPMyAdmin is written in PHP and can't be natively executed in Tomcat.

Comment: @JSS I see. I just need a way to execute queries directly on my website while still being able to use spring boot

Comment: Given security is not an issue in your use case. Can you not directly connect to your database using a SQL client such as squirrel-sql?

Comment: @JSS I can with no issue, however I am looking for something like sqlfiddle but instead of applying the changes in memory, I apply them directly to my MySQL db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing some things here: h2 is an in-memory-database. There is NO persistent storage. MySQL is a proper RDBMS. I would not expect you to be able to connect to mysql through that interface.

If you just need to be able to execute queries from your web application, and it is not going to go public, simply create a page with a textarea, send that to the backend using JDBC. If I have misunderstood your question, please add additional details to it so we cn provide a better answer.

Comment: So use jdbcTemplate.query(<input_string>)? And then just output each line? Is it that simple?

Comment: I would think so. i gather that `jdbcTemplate` is your jdbc connection object?

Comment: void query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, RowCallbackHandler rch) 
          Query using a prepared statement, reading the ResultSet on a per-row basis with a RowCallbackHandler.

from: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html

looks like it just might be that simple. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great stuff. Don't forget that if you put this into production (serve it up on the web for everyone to see), you need to secure your application properly. Sanitize your inputs, don't allow people to run arbitrary commands, etc.